# How to do a toUpperCase in the following replace?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which adds styling to text:

```
function convertStyling(text, orig) {
  if (orig.match(/\*\*|\*|\^\^/)) {
    return massReplace(text, 
      [ [ /\*\*([\w][^\*\*]*)\*\*/g, '<strong>$1</strong>'], 
        [ /\*([\w^][^\*]*)\*/g,      '<em>$1</em>' ],
        [ /\^\^([\w][^\^]*)\^\^/g,   '<span class="small-caps">$1</span>' ] ])
  }
}
```

Now I would like to do `toUpperCase()` to the last replace, but I'm confused, I guess I can't do `<span class="small-caps">$1.toUpperCase();</span>`?

Comment: `[ /\^\^([\w][^\^]*)\^\^/g,  function(m,m1){ return  '<span class="small-caps">' + m1.toUpperCase() + '</span>' } ]`

Comment: what if you do `text.toUpperCase()` ?   if your regex is not case sensitive it will make do difference to search result

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
 text-transform: uppercase;
```

JS:

```
 $('.small-caps').toUpperCase();
```

I would suggest using CSS.

Comment: They are [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that allow you to select elements. In this example I am selecting based on CSS class.